Should I install our toilet on top of the subfloor or on top of the PVT?
We just bought a new home (first-time!) which had carpet in the bathroom. Our goal was to replace the carpet with COREtec LVT. Unfortunately, when we pulled up the carpet, we saw that the plywood subfloor had water damage in some parts.
For comparison, here is the subfloor to left of the toilet which is in decent shape.

And here is the subfloor next to the bathtub which has those splotchy patches of water damage and maybe even signs of biological growth.

We stopped by Lowes and bought some replacement pressure-treated plywood as well as a new toilet. Our question:
What is considered best practice in this scenario? Should we replace the plywood, install the LVT, and then put the toilet on top? Or should we put in the toilet right after replacing the plywood and then cut/install the LVT around it?
Would appreciate any additional tips, tricks, common pitfalls to avoid, etc since this is a DIY project.

A good reason for putting the toilet on top of the finished floor is if the toilet has to be changed one day, and the new toilet base is a different shape than the old one. The cut flooring won't match up.

You surely puts toilets ON the TILE right?!?  Not on the subfloor!

Subfloor then flange then finish flooring then adequately thick wax ring then toilet then rubber toilet shims then acrylic latex caulk.

To clarify, that is the order of installation operations, not the order of layering.

@Huesmann which of these goes below the other, if the order is not the order of layering (while also being the order of install)? I guess one should determine the toilet shim placement before placing the wax ring.

@AdamO well, you don't put the finish flooring over the flange!

Welcome! I see based on upvotes that this is the correct answer, but it's not exactly an informative answer, as-is. It could be improved if a justification were given for why this is the correct order, instead of a run-on sentence. OP (or future readers) have no way to understand why this is correct in this instance, and whether this answer is transferable to similar toilet installs.

The tile should be cut to fit the flange, not the whole toilet. In the end, you want the edge of the porcelain base resting on tile (or other finished flooring), not subfloor.  As far as I know, this is primarily cosmetic rather than structural -- a toilet installed directly on a subfloor with tile cut around it would presumably work okay, but the result would look like... erm... the stuff you typically put in toilets.
For examples, see the pictures in this Home Depot toilet installation tutorial or this This Old House example on a wood floor or just do a Google image search of "toilet installation" or "toilet flange installation".
In both of the above-linked examples -- and in apparent contradiction to the advice in the other answer and its associated comment -- the flange was clearly installed after and on top of the finished floor, though I've also seen (in my own home for example) cases where the flange was clearly installed first and the final floor cut around it (i.e., no overlap of the flange over the tile).
But, either way, you want the toilet base completely overlapping final flooring.
